# How to make composer recognize particular github vendor namespace in general instead of specifying each repository from the same vendor separately

Tags: php, composer-php, package-managers

I am using composer to install packages from my own private github account.

Right now, if I want to include any particular package from my github, every time I need to add new entry in `composer.json` under the `repositories` key, like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:VendorNamespace/GitHubRepository1.git",
        "no-api": true
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:VendorNamespace/GitHubRepository2.git",
        "no-api": true
    },
    .
    .
    .
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:VendorNamespace/GitHubRepository100.git",
        "no-api": true
    }
]
```

Instead of doing so, I would like composer to recognize that using `VendorNamespace` as the vendor part of a package points to particular GitHub account and not repeating the above entry for every particular package I want to include.

Comment: Out of curiosity: you have 100 repos on GitHub? And maybe take a look at [Private Packagist](https://packagist.com/)

Comment: Company I work in has many :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, unfortunatelly.

One solution would be to use [Private Packagist](https://packagist.com), or to boot up your own instance of packagist.org site which is open source: https://github.com/composer/packagist, which would then host your own private packages.